# ImageView: "layout_width" can not set by custom method from xml

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my app/build.gradle:

```
  kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"
  dataBinding {
        enabled = true
  }
```

I have RecyclerView adapter. Here xml `preview_offer_item.xml` layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Offer" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/preview_image_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

OK. It's work. Fine.

Now I want to calculate "**android:layout_width**" **only** in xml file:

So here change:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">    
    <data>
        <import type="com.myproject.android.customer.util.GuiUtil" />
        </data>    
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@{GuiUtil.getTileWidth()}"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"/>    
</layout>
```

Here method `GuiUtil.getTileWidth()`:

```
package com.myproject.android.customer.util;

public class GuiUtil {

    public static int getTileWidth() {
        return 200;
    }
}
```

In `RecyclerView` adapter **NO** setter method with annotation `@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")`.

I want to do all calculate **only** in XML file.

But I get error:

```
:app:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type int on android.widget.ImageView.
file:\myproject\app\src\main\res\layout\preview_offer_item.xml
loc:26:36 - 26:57
****\ data binding error ****      org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
```

How I can fix this without write setter method?

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion on Android issue tracker, it is impossible to set layout height or width with data binding without creating custom binding adapters:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180666
You need to create a method to set the height like this :

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, int height) {
    LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Or using XML:

```
android:layout_width="@{GuiUtil.getTileWidth() == 200 ? @dimen/yourDimension1 : @dimen/yourDimension2, default=wrap_content}"
```

Comment: But if I have 3 imageView in xml. The method "setLayoutHeight" will call for EVERY imageView? But I need to change height only , e.g. for second imageView

Comment: Not help. Get same error: data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type float on android.widget.ImageView.